# How to reduce initialization page loading time in webpack angular 2 ?

Tags: angular, webpack

In my angular 2 application . i wanted to reduce the time of page loading . When i load the page for the first-time it takes 13 sec to load . Please help me with suggestions.

Comment: Do you use the -prod or -aot flags when running/building the application?

Comment: No . I am using for development mode . not using this flags

Comment: Minify CSS and JS by using -prod when building.

Answer (score 1):

Also apply **AOT** on top of the Webpack it will make drastic change in performance.

Follow below instructions it may be help to you.

- Build the application in production mode
- Bundle the Js and CSS file
- Load images with SubDomain
- Implement lazy loading where possible

Comment: lazy loading need to be implemented

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Angular 4. It is much faster

Comment: how to convert web-pack to angular 4?

Comment: angular 4 is based on webpack. So just do normal upgrade to latest version npm update --save --save-dev. Yuo can install npm-check and it will upgrade all dependencies in more user friendly way if you wish
Just remember that you need to have versions specified in package.json files check if you have ^ or * in front of the versions. Or simply overwrite it manually like "@angular/core": "^4.2.2"

Answer (score 0):

What is recommended is that when developing you don`t need to use the prod and aot flags because the compile time is way longer but when building the application for production try using

```
ng build -aot -prod
```

it should make it a lot faster. Be aware that some errors may occur in this mode so make to sure to test your workflows before deploying.

Comment: ng doesn't recognized as a command as i am using web pack .(Not using CLI)

Comment: Should be `--prod`, not `-prod`. Also, you don't need `--aot` if you're passing `--prod` - the latter will turn on AOT as well.

Comment: No i am doing it in development mode

Comment: Try following this guide then
https://angular.io/guide/deployment#webpack-and-aot